# Настройка групповых политик

Tags: windows, администрирование, active-directory

1. Есть административный шаблон, который определяет некий параметр со значениями 0 и 1
2. Есть два пользователя `User1`, `User2`
3. Есть два компьютера `Comp1`, `Comp2`

Вопрос, можно ли так настроить групповые политики, чтобы при подключении пользователей к компьютерам, значение параметра из шаблона устанавливалось по таким правилам

```
      Comp1 Comp2
User1   0     1
User2   1     0
```

Comment: Увы, но нет. Вы можете назначить политику каждому пользователю, если они в разных OU, и каждому компьютеру при тех же условиях. Какой-либо условный выбор не поддерживается. А что вы таким образом сделать хотите?

Comment: Я почитал и другие ваши вопросы на эту тему, они все вокруг одних и тех же действий крутятся. Вы не могли бы сформулировать цельный концепт решаемой задачи, потому что у меня четкое ощущение, что вы не с той стороны к вопросу подошли... AD и GPO мощное средство, но только при правильном применении. Стандартные программистские подходы тут плохо работают, в том смысле, что быстро "на коленке" решения может и не быть совсем, а если чуть сложнее и вдумчиво, то есть, и даже не одно. Это из личного опыта если что.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что я подхожу не с той стороны. Но опыта в администрировании примерно ноль. Потому и тыкаюсь. Весь концепт описал в этом вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857118/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC