# Выдача разрешений "многие ко многим"

Tags: windows, администрирование, active-directory

Есть куча TCP серверов (~100) на которые подключаются пользователи. Пользователи могут отправлять серверу определенные команды. Требуется обеспечить выдачу разрешений пользователям (или группе пользователей) на отправку тех или иных команд, но с учетом того, что действие этих разрешений ограничено одним или несколькими серверами.

Пример:

- Есть команды `A`, `B`
- Есть три сервера `S1`, `S2`, `S3`
- Есть три пользователя `U1`, `U2`, `U3`

Нужно обеспечить выдачу таких разрешений (0 - разрешено, 1 - запрещено)

- Для команды `A`

  ```
      S1 S2 S3
  U1  1  1  1
  U2  0  0  1
  U3  1  0  1
  ```
- Для команды `B`

  ```
      S1 S2 S3
  U1  1  1  1
  U2  0  1  1
  U3  1  1  0
  ```

TCP сервер и клиенты мои

Структура серверов иерархична и права пользователю могут выдаваться как на конкретный сервер или группу серверов, так и на некоторое поддерево серверов

Answer (score 1):

Для управления правами можно и нужно использовать группы безопасности, как локальные, так и доменные.

В вашем случае лучший (и понятный администраторам) вариант - использовать локальные группы на серверах, для определения прав на конкретные команды и доменные, для группировки пользователей.

Например:

Команде "A" - соответствует группа **CommandA**, команде "В" соответствует группа **CommandB**. Эти группы должны быть локальными для сервера, на котором хостится служба. Можно автоматизировать их создание с помощью простого скрипта, распространяемого с помощью GPO (объект групповой политики) или в инсталляторе.

Далее администратору необходимо только включить нужных пользователей в данные группы после развертывания очередного сервера. Если несколько пользователей должны иметь одинаковые права, то нужно создать доменную группу и уже эту доменную группу включить в локальные группы, соответствующие необходимым командам.

Доменные группы для пользователей имеет смысл создать независимо от количества пользователей, если вы хотите максимально автоматизировать процесс. В домене для каждого сервера можно создать персональный GPO и в нем настроить правила включения локальных групп в доменные.

Управление службами windows настраивается довольно специфически ([тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709316/198316)), но поддается автоматизации скриптами, хоть и с зубодробительным синтаксисом. Тут группы тоже очень пригодятся, т.к. проще выдать права группе и добавлять в нее пользователей, чем прописывать права каждому пользователю.

Со стороны программы для проверки прав достаточно получить список групп, в которых состоит пользователь (например через WMI или классы System.DirectoryServices) и проверить наличие нужных групп, можно просто по имени, т.к. группы локальные, или по [DN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ldap/distinguished-names), это точнее, у локальных групп оно тоже есть, но немного проще по структуре, чем доменное. Использовать для проверки SID не имеет большого смысла, т.к. от сервера к серверу SID локальной группы может и, с большой вероятностью, будет меняться, в тоже время в DN группы будет меняться только имя сервера, которое легко получить и подставить не меняя остальные компоненты DN.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Идея ясна. Только получается, что нужно будет отконфигурировать **каждый** сервер. А основная задача - обеспечить централизованную настройку прав. При том, что в большинстве случаев сервера можно объединить в группы. Пока +1, потому, что ответ однозначно полезен и дал новую пищу для размышлений.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov ну базовая конфигурация сервера всегда индивидуальна. Если их нужно объединить в группы, то в описанную схему добавятся доменные группы безопасности для команд на группе серверов. Конечно количество групп будет расти, но это неизбежное зло на текущей инфраструктуре AD. Альтернатива только хардкорный скриптинг с проверками множества условий, но это совсем не удобно сопровождать и количество потенциальных багов вырастет по экспоненте =( для 3-5 серверов с это не проблема, для 100+ сами понимаете...

Comment: И главное - сильно мне не нравится идея идентификации групп по имени

Comment: @AntonShchyrov DN гарантирует уникальность в домене и локально. Обычное имя в общем тоже, но по нему не поймёшь откуда конкретно группа или пользователь

Comment: Про уникальность я понимаю. Я не понимаю как его задать в программе. Жестко вкомпиливать не хочется. Вот если бы группе выставить некий признак

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Зачем? Простенький конфигуратор для сервиса, в котором можно выбрать нужные группы для команд из существующих и сохранить их в конфиге сервиса

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Собственно так и сиды получить можно, если имена не нравятся

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Ещё можно уговорить администратора домена внести изменения в схему AD и таки добавить признак группе, да и вообще что угодно, но все равно придётся писать инструмент для настройки этих дополнительных атрибутов. Стандартные интерфейсы работают только со стандартными атрибутами, остальное через консоль или самописные штуки, да и админа будет сложно уговорить, если он "плавает" в управлении AD